# Sorting a 2 dimensional array of objects in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, sorting, object

I have a static 2 dimensional array of objects in a Kotlin project:

```
class Tables {
    companion object{
        lateinit var finalTable: Array<Array<Any?>?>
    }
}
```

It is a little clearer in Java:

```
public class Tables {

    public static Object[][] finalTable;
}
```

The third element in one row of objects in the table, is a string boxed as an object. In other words: finalTable[*][2] is a string describing the item. When I add an item to the array in Kotlin, I want to sort the entire array in alphabetical order of the description.

In Java this is easy:

```
 Arrays.sort(Tables.finalTable, Comparator.comparing(o -> (String) o[2]));
```

When I try to use Android Studio to translate the Java code into Kotlin, it produces the following:

```
Arrays.sort( Tables.finalTable, Comparator.comparing( Function { o: Array<Any?>? -> o[2] as String }) )
```

This does not work, you have change the String cast as follows:

```
Arrays.sort( Tables.finalTable, Comparator.comparing( Function { o: Array<Any?>? -> o[2].toString() }) )
```

This version will compile and run, but it totally messes up the sorting of the table, so it does not work. I have tried variations on this theme, without any success. To get my project to work, I had to create a Java class in the Kotlin project with the functional Java code listed above:

```
public class ArraySort {
    public void sortArray(){
        Arrays.sort(Tables.finalTable, Comparator.comparing(o -> (String) o[2]));
    }
}
```

This sorts the table like a charm, but I would prefer to keep my project "pure Kotlin". Can anyone suggest a pure Kotlin method to sort such an array? Thanks!

Comment: Bad solution but works  -> `Tables.finalTable.filterNotNull().map{ outer -> outer.filterNotNull().map { inner -> inner as String } }.sortedBy { it[2] }`   Not sure why you have type Any instead of String inf first place. This will throw an exception if you don't have finalTable[*][2] element

Comment: `Tables.finalTable.filterNotNull().map{ outer -> outer.filterNotNull().map { inner -> inner as String }.filter {it.length >=3 } }.sortedBy { it[2] }` returns sorted list which only has elemt finalTable[*][2]

Comment: This throws an exception "You cannot cast an integer to string." You seem to cast the whole inner to string. That won't work, as inner[0] is an integer this is followed by some strings and floats in the inner row. However, index [2] is the description string. Thanks for posting, anyway.

Comment: I posted my comment based on your first post. I will now try your second. Tried your second suggestion. Got he same exception. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you post some example data of your Array<Array<Any?>?>

Comment: It will take a while to get a readable version of the table, but I will try. :-)

Comment: Your last suggestion gave a different exception: Cannot cast ArrayList to String. Kotlin reads, saves and edits the mixed table just fine, I just cannot get it to sort the table.  Maybe I should just stick to the Java class version that works just fine.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake :) try this `Tables.finalTable.filterNotNull().map{ outer -> outer.filterNotNull() }.filter { it.size >= 3 }.sortedBy { it[2] as String }` it will work I hope

Comment: Even this will throw an exception if the element finalTable[*][2] is not a String. Kotlin and Java both won't support dynamic type arrays. In your code, you are using type Any and in Kotlin everything is inherited from the type so that's the reason your code compiles. In java, it's `java.lang.Object`

Comment: No exceptions this time, but it does not sort the table. Thanks for all your effort. I am just going to go with the Java solution that works!

Comment: 1) If you have different types in different inner array positions, then it sounds like an array isn't a good fit. Perhaps an object instead? (Creating well-behaved data objects is _far_ simpler in Kotlin than Java.) E.g. `sortedBy{ it.description }` is far more readable (and safer) than `sortedBy{ it[2] as String }`.

Comment: 2) Lists are generally better than arrays: better supported in the stdlib, work better with generics, different implementations to choose from, have a useful `toString()`, etc. Arrays are needed for interoperability, varargs, and `main()` params, but for everything else lists are likely to save trouble.

Comment: Your comments noted, thanks! Note that I used a 2 dimensional array of objects, precisely because one row in the array contains different types (integers, strings and floats). I will nevertheless take a deeper look into lists!

Comment: Thanks. Based on your comment, I am converting the project to lists. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, [you can just do this](https://pl.kotl.in/7hHneZjvA):

```
Tables.finalTable.sortBy { it[2] as String }
```

which sorts your array in place. `sortedBy` will produce a new copy of the original if that's what you want instead, and might be why the comment suggestions weren't working for you.

But this whole unstructured array situation isn't ideal, the solution is brittle because it would be easy to put the wrong type in that position for a row, or have a row without enough elements, etc. Creating a data structure (e.g. a `data class`) would allow you to have named parameters you can refer to (making the whole thing safer and more readable) and give you type checking too

Comment: Aaaaaaah! So simple and yet it works! Thanks for your input. After all is said and done, I may do the following: It may be more robust programming if instead of creating an object array of rows of objects, where each row contains data about a food type, I create a food class that I instantiate for every food type, and then configure a list of food objects. Does that make sense? I think so!

Comment: @neelshenning Yeah it's definitely safer and easier to work with! And self-documenting if you pick good names for the properties - `Tables.finalTable.sortBy { it.description }` (or `Tables.finalTable.sortBy(FoodType::description)`) is a lot easier to understand. Not just what's happening, but also what the person who wrote it *intended* - an index in an array of *stuff* is a lot more vague, y'know? Arrays might be better if you absolutely need the memory efficiency, but most people don't - and if you do you'll know exactly why!